# Using loop to write in files

Tags: pycharm, python-3.4

I am trying to download the raw code from all the tutorials I've been watching, so I made this:

```
import requests
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_url='https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-
Tutorials/tree/master/Python'

def page(main_url):
    code=requests.get(main_url)
    text=code.text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'js-navigation-open'}):
        code_url='https://github.com'+link.get('href')
        codelist(code_url)

def codelist(sec_url):
    code = requests.get(sec_url)
    text = code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'id': 'raw-url'}):
        raw_url='https://github.com'+link.get('href')
        rawcode(raw_url)

def rawcode(third_url):
    response = request.urlopen(third_url)
    txt = response.read()
    lines = txt.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r'go.py'
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()

page(page_url)
```

When I run this code am expecting to create 40 py files consisting of 40 different codes from here-https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-Tutorials/tree/master/Python
But it doesn't work. Twice, it randomly chose to download just one of the 40 files. Like this-

The first two functions work well together until the third one is called. But the third works fine alone.

I started learning Python 4 days back, any help will be much appreciated. Thank you, guys!

Comment: You're written over your file, which delete the previous file and its content. Try `fx = open(dest_url, "a")`, which will (a)dd the code instead of re-(w)ritten it

Comment: Best would be to save in different files (you can do it using a simple counter which will increment thus change the file names). So you can run them after

Comment: @Nuageux Thank you, sir. Can't imagine that a single letter solved it.
But still, all the code was downloaded in a single file. What would you recommend to loop it such that 40 different files are created?
Thanks, again.

Comment: @Nuageux Changed last function to this, sir -
   `x=2
    response = request.urlopen(third_url)
    txt = response.read()
    txt_str=str(txt)
    lines = txt_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = str(x)+'.py'
    fx = open(dest_url, "a")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()
    x+=1`
It created a file "2.py" and saved everything in it. Is my code wrong?

Comment: You defined `x=2` at the beginning of your function, so it is always equal to 2. I'll edit my answer so you can just copy/past

Comment: Just did it. I also added some comment for you to better understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Following the comments] In order to change easily your file names, you can add a global variable (here `cp`) such as follow:

```
def rawcode(third_url):
    global cp
    dest_url = r'go_%s.py' % cp
    cp += 1
    print(dest_url)

cp = 0
page(page_url)
```

The file names will be "`go_X.py"` with X from 0 to the number of files

**edit**
With your code:

```
def rawcode(third_url):
    response = request.urlopen(third_url)
    txt = response.read()
    lines = txt.split("\\n")
    global cp # We say that we will use cp the global variable and not local one
    dest_url = r'go_%s.py' % cp
    cp += 1 # We increment for further calls
    fx = open(dest_url, "w") # We can keep 'w' since we will generate new files at each call
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()

cp = 0 # Initialisation
page(page_url)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. You made my day. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark your question as answered

Comment: Am not sure how to do that, Sir. Am very new here.